# R .External error: caught segfault 'memory not mapped'

Tags: r, c

I'm trying some .External examples and I got this error:

```
eras(155)

 *** caught segfault ***
address 0x556a1f30e334, cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
 1: .External("eratostenes", as.integer(n))
 2: eras(155)
```

The C code is as follows:

```
#include <R.h>
#include <Rinternals.h>

SEXP eratostenes (SEXP args)
{
    SEXP out, vector, number;
    int n, k, j, cuantos;

    args = CDR(args);

    number = CAR(args);

    n = asInteger(number);

    int P[n+1];

    PROTECT(vector = allocVector(INTSXP, n));

    for (k=0; k<n; k++){
        P[k] = 0;
        INTEGER(vector)[k] = 0;
    }
    P[k] = 0;

    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++ ){
        if ( !P[i] ){
            INTEGER(vector)[cuantos] = i;
            cuantos++;
        }

        j = 1;
        while ( i*j<=n ){
            P[i*j] = 1;
            j++;
        }
    }

    PROTECT(out = allocVector(INTSXP, cuantos));

    for (int i = 0; i < cuantos; ++i){
        INTEGER(out)[i] = INTEGER(vector)[i];
    }

    UNPROTECT(2);

    return out;
}
```

I now there is redundant code, but I'm still learning this.
In R, I call this function like this:

```
dyn.load("file.so")
eras <- function(n){
    stopifnot(n>0)

    return(.External("eratostenes",as.integer(n)))
}
eras(155)
```

The output of `R CMD SHLIB file.c` is:

```
gcc -std=gnu99 -std=gnu11 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-i2PIHO/r-base-4.1.2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c file.c -o file.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -std=gnu11 -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o file.so file.o -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
```

I'm in ubuntu 20.04 and this is my R version:

```
R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01) -- "Bird Hippie"
Copyright (C) 2021 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
```

I've tried similar C code without issues and I can't really see the problem because it compiles just fine. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `cuantos` is used whilst uninitialised. Set `int cuantos = 0;` before using it.

Comment: "*it compiles just fine*". It would be a wonderful world if all programs were guaranteed to run correctly as long as it compiles. In C especially that is not the case and you should make no such assumption.

Comment: I was thinking it might related to when the unprotect(2) was called, that I imagined you might want to do after you return `out`. Just seems you'd want to preserve memory space till it is actually no longer required (as, what could go wrong?). But this is just a guess.

Comment: @kaylum what a silly mistake T_T... that's what happen when working late lol... thanks, the initialization of cuantos was the problem, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

as pointed out by @kaylum, I was missing on initializing the variable `cuantos`.